# Snippet backgroud color neovim/vim

Tags: terminal, colors, background, neovim

Does anybody know how can I change this background?
The dark blue color in neovim.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neovim autocompletion uses hightlight for colors of autocomplete menu with highlight groups `Pmenu`, `PmenuSbar` and `PmenuSel`.

To change selection color, set `Pmenu` highlight group with your colors :

```
hi PmenuSel ctermbg=251 ctermfg=237 guibg=#cad0de guifg=#33374c
```